# angularjs - same controller, different methods/variable for different routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to have the same controller, but exposes different scope methods/variable for different routes?

I am currently using ui-router and would like to expose different methods/variables for `/new`, `/edit`, `/delete`

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't it make more sense to have the same template but with different  controllers?

Comment: I would agree with you on that, having the same controller behaving differently i believe will violate Open-close principle for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Using `ui-router`,

```
angular.module("myModule")
.controller("myController",function($scope,$stateParams){
    if ($stateParams.mySubView === "/new") {
       $scope.hello = function(){alert("Hello")};
    } else {
       $scope.hello = function(){alert("Hi")};
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have all routes pointing to the same controller, but in the controller use the $stateParams to determine which method it needs to invoke. Don't think it needs to be any harder than that? Unless I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes, that'd work perfectly. I was wondering if there is a way to move more of the logic into the `$stateProvider` where I can just specify  a method that would invoke a function with all the variables and $scope methods